# Wordpress config: How to set a hook to set a define?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to make a plugin that can set some defines, like WP_HOME, WP_DATABASE, etc. Anyone know if that can be done and what hook I should call?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the `init` (or `admin_init`, depending on the place you need it) hook. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init

```
add_action('init', 'loadConstants');

function loadConstants() {
//WP_HOME and other goes here
}
```